Find limit: $f_{n+1} = \frac{f_n + g _n}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{g_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{f_n} + \frac{1}{g_n}$
$f_1$ and $g_1$ are positive numbers. The sequences $<f_n>$ and $<g_n>$ are such that:
$$f_{n+1} = \frac{f_n + g _n}{2}$$
and
$$\frac{2}{g_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{f_n} + \frac{1}{g_n}$$
I have to show that they are convergent. I could do that. How do I find the limit of the two sequences?

Note : it is the arithmetico-harmonic mean of $f$ and $g$ (the respective limit).

Since you say you already showed that they are convergent, let $f$ and $g$ be their limits. Then $f = (f+g)/2$ implies that $f=g$. Note that for any $n\ge 1$, $f_n g_n = f_1 g_1$. Therefore, $f=g= \sqrt{f_1 g_1}$.
